# Mongoose post save hook only runs once

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have a post save hook in Mongoose that works the first time I send a request to the route. It properly updates the property that I've specified. The issue comes the subsequent times when I send a post request to the route. Nothing happens and I can see the request hanging in Postman. Any ideas as to what I could be missing?

**Code**

```
let mongoose = require('mongoose');
let Schema = mongoose.Schema;

let SubscriberSchema = new Schema({
    id: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    firstName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    lastName: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    emailAddress: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    },
    phoneNumber: {
        type: String,
        required: false
    },
    clientId: {
        type: String,
        required: true
    }
});

SubscriberSchema.post('save', (doc) => {
    doc.id = doc._id;
    doc.save();
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Subscriber', SubscriberSchema);
```

Comment: Mongoose uses `id` and `_id` interchangeably for the same thing, so you cannot supply your own field with that name. You're also stepping dangerously into "recursion" territory by attempting to call the same `save()` method inside the hooks that fire after that method is called. So it's actually fortunate here this does not work.

Comment: I wasn't aware of the `id` / `_id` issue. Thanks for pointing that out, @NeilLunn. I believe that I'm missing the way to properly implement a post save hook. If I were to update a different property in a post save hook, wouldn't I need to run the `save()` method again? If not, what is the proper way to do something like that?